# post request with json data cross domain

Tags: json, ajax, post, cross-domain, httprequest

I have been reading tutorials for two days and I really cant understand what are my options. I have a machine with HMI that runs web server (I dont know what kind of web server that is). I can acces HMI tags values trought POST request with json data.
The rquest example look like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    var data0 = {"getTags":["Start_dav","CutON","run_rot_actual"],"includeTagMetadata":true};     
    var json = JSON.stringify(data0 );

           $.ajax({
                url: "http://ipaddress/tagbatch",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: json,
```

The response is json data.

The problem is of course in cross domain policy. I have no control over the machine and there is no option to set up CORS. I have read about proxy, iframe and yql solutions but as I understand I cant send json data with these workarounds. Is there any way how to send post request with json cross domain?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am using php curl for sending a request.

Here is the working code:

```
$data = array("getTags" => array("Var1","Var2"), "includeTagMetadata" => false);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.0.9) Gecko/20061206 Firefox/1.5.0.9';
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w'); //writes headers to this file
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"domainipaddress");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
$tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; //saves the cookie from server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,  CURLOPT_VERBOSE,  1 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,  CURLOPT_STDERR,  $f );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                        
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
       'Connection: keep-alive',
       "Keep-Alive: 300"
    )                                                                       
);  

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
fclose($f);
```